# Why are RegexParsers definied with "def" instead of "lazy val"?

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators

In the Scaladoc about [RegexParsers](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers), there is the following code:

```
object Calculator extends RegexParsers {
  def number: Parser[Double] = """\d+(\.\d*)?""".r ^^ { _.toDouble }
  def factor: Parser[Double] = number | "(" ~> expr <~ ")"
...
```

I don't see why we it's written with a `def` and not with a `val` or a `lazy val` ? I would write like this :

```
object Calculator extends RegexParsers {
  lazy val number: Parser[Double] = """\d+(\.\d*)?""".r ^^ { _.toDouble }
  lazy val factor: Parser[Double] = number | "(" ~> expr <~ ")"
...
```

Comment: def definitions have much less overhead since they are compiled into usual method calls, whereas lazy vals have double checked initialization and bitset field underneath.

Comment: But a `def` means that the regex will be recreated every time. Couldn't this lead to some performance penalty ?

Comment: Avoid premature optimisation. Also, don't expect that code examples in Scaladoc are ready for you to copy into your production application without modification!

Comment: In my experience using defs does lead to non-trivial performance penalties, particularly for grammars that involve deeply nested expression structures.

Answer (score 1):

There is an actual semantic reason for it. Look at the type signature for `Parser`:

```
 abstract class Parser[+T] extends (Input) ⇒ ParseResult[T]
```

`Parser[T]` is in fact a function from some abstract kind of `Input` to a `ParseResult[T]`. In many (probably most) cases this function captures some aspect of the state of the parse being carried out. If such a production were captured in a `val`, (lazy or otherwise) it could not be used in more than one place in a given parse tree. The only productions that can be made `val` are fixed terminals such as punctuation and keywords.

**Addendum**

It has been years since I've worked on Scala combinator parsers and I was comparatively a Scala newbie at the time, so it's entirely possible I was simply mistaken. However, my recollection is that that `Reader` represented not the input as a whole but rather a specific sub-sequence of that input. Thus if the production did not have a fixed input sequence, the production could not be a `val`.

I actually do have a little side project that needs a parser, so when I get some time, I can either confirm or refute that understanding.

Comment: This has not been my experience. I use lazy vals (or val) for my parser definitions and can't recall ever having a problem due to "captured state". My understanding is that the state of the input and the result of the parse are enough to communicate state information between parsers so there is no need for the parsers themselves to remember anything. Do you have a concrete example of where it goes wrong?